# PHP output calculated SQL value

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to add all the values in a single column from a table and then echo that value

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
$sql = "SELECT sum(paid) as total_paid from users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result;
```

But I end up getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in

Why and how can I fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too long for a "comment".

You need to loop over the results and use a `while` loop, rather than echoing the query which is why you're getting the present error.

You also need to make sure that the `paid` column's type can be used to perform mathematical problems, such as `int` for instance (*for example*). If it's `varchar`, then you will need to cast it to an integer.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html

Here is a procedural style method:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(paid) as total_paid from users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "Sum: " . $row['total_paid'];
}
```

or as an object-oriented method:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo $sum = $row['total_paid'];
        }
```

Sidenote:

To calculate a row based on a user/id, add a `WHERE` clause in your query.

I.e.: `WHERE id='x'`

Comment: "such as `int` for instance" made me double take. It makes sense, but comes across funny. Maybe that's just me :)

Comment: @Martin `int` is but one of a few types that can be used to perform math in MySQL. There are a few others. Although I could add a link to the MySQL's website for the different types that can perform math.

Comment: I was referring to "`int` for instance", I read that as just that, it does makes sense but it made me double read and then laugh at the coincidence that `int` as a value type in MySQL can also in this sentence imply *instance*.

Comment: @Martin ah, I see what you mean now. The "for instance" meant "for example".

Comment: hah, yeah I know what it meant it was solely the order and shape of the words in the sentence came across as amusing to me. (And now I feel stupid that this all needed over explaining.) haha, anyhow, your answer's fine, I just had an amusing interpretation. * goes back to looking for money under stones , grunting occasionally *

Comment: @Martin Word placement can be interpreted differently for sure ;-) I made a slight edit for it, *cheers*

Answer (score 4):

This because `$result` returns an object, not a string. You have to loop through it and echo the results. And since it is only one row (because `SUM` without a `group by` ***always returns only one value, therefore only one row***), you can do this:

```
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['total_paid'];
}
```

Or, use [`fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) directly:

```
echo $result->fetch_object()->total_paid;
```

Comment: its nit one row, its multiple rows. it's one column

Comment: @Rhillz `SUM` without `group by` ***always*** returns one and only one row

Comment: @Rhillz Yes, it will return only one value, hence it will be only one row.

Comment: @Rhillz - Have you tried the code? Does it work fine or not??

Comment: I'm still getting this undefined variable error: $sql = "SELECT sum(paid) as total_paid from users"; $result = $conn->query($sql); echo $result->fetch_object()->total_paid